# mysqldump misses table data

Tags: unix, mysql

I want to make a full-dump of my databases. So I used ...

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <user> -p<password> -q --single-transaction --triggers --routines --compress <database> > dump.sql
```

... to dump my data to a file (4.271.663.366 Bytes > 3,97GB). I find a create statement for my table, but no insert data.
If I dump the table separate into a file, all works.

**Here some info:**

Database info:

- Table count: 215
- Records: 32105706
- Typ: InnoDB (some MyIsam)
- Size: 6.5 GiB

The table with problems:

- Records: 31178
- Typ: InnoDB
- Size: 12.5 MiB

Create Statement of this table (created with phpmyadmin export -> structure only):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `<table-name>` (
  `<field>` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `<field>` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `<field>` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `<field>` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `<field>` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `<field>` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `<field>` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '<comment>',
  `<field>` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`<field>`),
  UNIQUE KEY `<field>` (`<field>`),
  KEY `<field>` (`<field>`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10500127 ;

--
-- Trigger `<field>`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `<table-trigger>`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `<table-trigger>` BEFORE DELETE ON `<table-name>`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @DISABLE_TRIGER_other_trigger=1;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;  
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  DELETE FROM <other-table> WHERE <field> = OLD.<field>;
  SET @DISABLE_TRIGER_other_trigger=NULL;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL-Dump:
mysqldump --version

> mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump -u <USER> -p <db_name> > mysqldump.sql`

and import using

`mysql -u <USER> -p <db_name> < mysqldump.sql`

does the trick for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do I miss something? I do the same (just, more parameters for mysqldump). In my "mysqldump.sql" there are no INSERT-Statements for one table.